# Controlling visibility of multiple dashboards in tableau dashboard

Tags: tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I have 4 parameters that controls the visibility of 4 dashboards in same canvas. I wanted to create a button (+/-) such that the visibility is controlled by these buttons and also at a time only one dashboard is visible. Can anybody help to achieve this task.

Please feel free to ask any additional details required.

I tried to create a new parameter that will control the values of 4 parameters for each dashboard, but that doesn't work.